# Taking Green's Theorem from 3D

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions, vector-fields, greens-theorem

I'm trying to understand the application for Green's Theorem for a field with singularities and taken from 3D to 2D point of view. So lets say I have this field $F(x, y, z) = (\frac{z}{x^2+y^2} + x, y, \frac{-x}{x^2+y^2} + z)$. I need the work done by the field along the ellipse $2(x-1)^2+\frac{y^2}{4} = 2; z = 0$.

Because $z = 0$ can I consider the field that does work really just $F^z(x, y) = (x, y)$? And if I were, for example, at the point $(0, 10, 0)$, could I just ignore the second term, being $F^y(x, z) = (\frac{z}{x^2+10}, \frac{x}{x^2+10} + z)$?

Comment: If you were on the plane $y=10$ then you could consider it. $z=0$ does not refer to a point but it refers to the plane $z=0$ (which is commonly known as the xy-plane)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the plane $z=0$ . The vector field is $F(x,y,z)=x\hat{i}+y\hat{j}-\frac{x}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\hat{k}$ .

The ellipse in the plane is parametrized by $\bigg\{\big(1+\cos(t),2\sqrt{2}\sin(t)\big):t\in[0,2\pi]\bigg\}$ .

Thus we have $\vec{dr}=-\sin(t)dt\hat{i}+2\sqrt{2}\cos(t)dt\hat{j}$

Thus $$\oint F\cdot \vec{dr}=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\bigg(-\big(1+\cos(t)\big)\sin(t)+8\cos(t)\sin(t)\bigg)dt = 0$$  .

You cannot directly apply Green's Theorem because of the singularity(Although it would lead to the correct answer). You have to show why and how the work done by the $\hat{k}$ component is $0$  . And this is done by showing that the vector $\vec{dr}$ . is orthogonal to $\hat{k}$ .

To answer your question about the "point" (0,10,0). Well ofcourse this is a function so it would have a value at each point. So at $(0,10,0)$ F would be just $10\hat{j}$ .

If you were on the plane $y=10$ . Then you can consider that the vector field is just $(\frac{z}{x^2+10}, \frac{x}{x^2+10} + z)$ .

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But why can't I consider the field just to have the components $F=(x, y)$ for the first case, removing a dimension, as I could do in the second case?

Comment: In reality you are not removing any dimensions. It's just that the work done by the $z$ component is $0$ that's why you are not required to consider it.  In the second case you can directly apply green's theorem because you are not encountering a singularity while on the plane $y=10$.

Comment: Oh, I see! I think I'm grasping it better now. And in order to show that it is orthogonal to the vector $\hat{k}$ does it suffice to show that $\vec{dr} \cdot (0, 0, 1) = 0$? But why the derivative of $r$ and not the ellipse itself - is it because the work done is the $\vec{F} \cdot \vec{dr}$?

Comment: If you want to prove that the work done by the $\hat{k}$ component of the force is $0$ , then it suffices to prove that the trajectory you are moving in is perpendicular to the plane . If $\hat{dr}\cdot \hat{k}=0$ then it means that the vector $\hat{k}$ is perpendicular to the trajectory at each point which. Note that if $F=hat{i}+\hat{j}$ and $r=(t,t^{2},t^{3}$ say . Then we don't have $\vec{dr}\cdot \hat{k}=0$. But as the work done by the $z-$ component of the force will again be zero because the z-force is $0$. In one word it's better to just put everything in the formula and see what is 0.